# Offset a button Fixed amount of Pixels from a text input

Tags: html, css

I currently have a text input that is centered on the page automatically but i have a button next to it that gets too separated or overlaps it depending how the screen is resized.. I currently have this

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .book2Button{

      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
      margin-left:70%;
      margin-right: 30%;
      position: fixed;

    }

    input[type="text"] {
      margin-left:50%;
      margin-right:50%;
      border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
      position: absolute;

    }
    </style>

    </head>
      <body>
        <div id = "a">
          <input type = "text" name = "zip"    placeholder = "ENTER ZIP"/>

          <a href = "book.html" class = "book2Button"> SUBMIT</a>
        </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

and my goal is something like the yahoo search bar with a button a fixed amount of pixels away no matter how the screen is resized. i have tried countless things such as changing the divs position, margins.. but i cant get it to work using html and css. Is there away to refer to the text input specifically and create the button with margins from there?

Comment: Positioning one of the two elements `fixed`, and the other `absolute` probably doesn’t make the most sense to begin with. I suggest you simply align the elements as you want them inside their container element – without any `position` – and then you position the container as a whole afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just center the div content using `text-align: center` or center the div itself using `margin: 0 auto;` then add `margin-left: 10px;` to the button.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPzwob